# ASUS Custom Build gets stuck on ASUS boot screen (with spinning dots)

Tags: boot, motherboard

My computer was working fine until I turned it off and went for dinner. Upon my return, the computer's boot up was stuck on the Asus (in search of incredible) screen with the spinning dots. I left it in that state for a good fifteen minutes and it remained like that until I returned.

I tried unplugging all my USB devices except my mouse from the computer (in case it was drawing too much power from the motherboard) and still the same result occurred. I attempted to boot up Linux Ubuntu from a USB stick, and it worked, so I am now confident that hardware is not the problem.

I can't even boot up my windows 10 in safe mode because my build has an SSD primary drive and I have know idea where the safe mode feature is on the Asus UEFI BIOS startup settings.

What are my options? What can I do?

By the way, I even unplugged one of my RAM sticks to see if anything would happen (I'm not sure how debug faulty RAM). When the computer booted it said "your computer failed to boot" then it gave me the option to restart or go advanced options.

Comment: Are you able to enter your BIOS/UEFI? Disable the fancy screen and have a look at what it's actually getting stuck on. Usually it's something called like Silent Boot or similar.

Comment: I am able to enter my UEFI, however I have no idea how to navigate the options and where to find that disable button.

Comment: Probably either in the tools section or boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach the W10 troubleshooting menu if you have encountered an error on startup, by clicking Advanced Options > Troubleshoot > Startup Options > Boot into Safe Mode.

Keep your mouse and keyboard plugged into the USB ports, you will need them to aid if a re-installation of your OS is necessary.

Create a Bootable MemTest86 USB drive, and run the extensive test that will stress some of the key components of your system(CPU, RAM) and report back if any errors are found.

If there are no issues with these components, move on to testing if your OS is corrupted, if you can only boot into the troubleshooting menu after restarting 'X' times, and can't get any further whether you System Reset or not, then you may need to reinstall your OS.

Alternatively, you may have a damaged component, GPU, RAM Module, etc.

To correctly test your RAM, try booting with only 1 stick in either A1 or B1 slots, and see if you can progress further than OS initialization.

Hope this helps.